# How to calculate the result of 3 operands with 2 operators?

Tags: c

As the title.
I get a problem, with 3 operands, every one is random, and with 2 operators are also random.

For example, it can be performed as : num1 [ops] num2 [ops] num3. User can input as "3+2/8", "45*76+8" or "14-8-9", ... ( '*' and '/' still have operator precedences).

If I use "if" to deal with it, it's not smart.
But if I use switch, it also need 4*4 cases, it's not smart, either.
So, how do I do?

Thanks for your looking, and I felt sorry with my bad English.

here is my code:

```
void judge(char *);
int main()
{
    char string[]={};
    while(gets(string)!=EOF)
    {
        judge(string);
    }
    return 0;
}

void judge(char *string)
{
    int i=0;
    int sum=0;

    char string2[10];
    strcpy(string2, string);

    char ops[2]={};
    int nums[3]={};
    char *delim =" +-*/";
    char *delim2=" 0123456789";
    char * pch;
    char * pch2;

    pch = strtok(string,delim);
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        nums[i]=atoi(pch);
        i++;
        pch = strtok (NULL, delim);
    }
    i=0;
    pch2 = strtok(string2,delim2);
    while (pch2 != NULL)
    {
        ops[i]=pch2[0];
        i++;
        pch2 = strtok (NULL, delim2);
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(i>0)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%d",nums[i]);
    }
    printf(" ");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        if(i>0)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%c",ops[i]);
    }


    /* here is what I confused. */
    switch(ops[0])
    {
        case '+':
            if(ops[1]=='+')
                sum=nums[0]+nums[1]+num[2];
            if(ops[1]=='-')
                sum=nums[0]+nums[1]-num[2];
            if(ops[1]=='*')
                sum=nums[0]+nums[1]*num[2];
            if(ops[1]=='/')
                sum=nums[0]+nums[1]/num[2];
    }
}
```

and the compiler window:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpg8w.png)

Comment: Are the operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`? Do you have to handle operator precedence? Please update your question with more details. You should also show the code of your proposed implementations.

Comment: Don't be "sorry for your bad english", but improve the question by asking help from someone who knows english better than you and/or use translate.google.com and/or show some examples which also may help us to understand what you are asking.

Comment: `a+b+c` is not a sum with 3 operand but two sum having 2 operand each

Comment: Thanks for comments, I learn very much.

Comment: Regarding the comment by @Bodo: the input "2+6*3" should evaluate to 24 or 20?

Comment: The result of 2+6*3 is 20, " * , / " still have the precedence.

Comment: @Ihatemyice OK, now it is clear what you want, but the question is too broad. Please read this: [ask] and this: [tour].

Comment: @Jabberwocky I will read the tour, thanks.

Comment: The question describes a quite artificial scenario. If it is a homework or other training assignment, you should describe what you have figured out so far and what specific problem you are having. If it is a real-world problem, you should explain how it arises and what the ultimate goal actually is—it is unlikely the question as described is a good approach for solving some real-world problem.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil It's just a simple C question.

Comment: Better insert your code into your question as a code block (using the {} function of the editor) instead of using an external service.

Comment: You might have to enable more warnings in the project's build options. Check all that enable more warnings or more strict checking. (but not "Inhibit all warning messages (-w)" or "Stop compiling after first error (-Wfatal-errors)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few typos in your code and you will get warnings because you did not include all necessary header files.

You cannot define an array without size like `char string[]`.

Depending on your compiler and C library you might get a warning about deprecated function `gets`. You should use `fgets` instead to avoid buffer overflow. Both functions return a pointer which may be `NULL`, but not `EOF`.

You should fix all compiler warnings first.

I will not write the full program (for now), but suggest some possible solutions.

For a smart solution you could implement a function that does a calculation `A op B` using a `switch` with 4 cases and call it twice. The function could be defined as

```
int calculate(int a, char op, int b)
```

With your calculation `A op1 B op2 C` you would first have to check the precedence of the operators `op1` and `op2` to decide if you calculate `( A op1 B ) op2 C` or `A op1 ( B op2 C)`. For this you could implement a function that returns the precedence of an operator. I assume a lower value is higher precedence. The function could be defined as

```
int precedence(char op)
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
if(precedence(ops[0]) < precedence(ops[1])) {
    return calculate( calculate(nums[0], ops[0], nums[1]),
                      ops[1], nums[2] );
} else {
    return calculate( nums[0], ops[0],
                      calculate(nums[1], ops[1], nums[2]) );
}
```

In the program from the question you might want to use `sum = calculate( ... )` instead of `return calculate( ... )`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.